# What happens when a consumer has both a negative acknowledge and a retry policy set

Tags: apache-pulsar

For Apache Pulsar, are **negative acknowledge** and **retry topic** policies mutually exclusive, or do they somehow work together? What if you enable both? What would the failure progression of a single message be if you continually nack it or fail to ack it in time?

I could not figure this out by reading the latest documentation.

For example, let's say I've configured a consumer this way (using the .NET **Pulsar.Client**):

```cs
var consumer = _client.NewConsumer()
    .SubscriptionType(SubscriptionType.KeyShared)
    .SubscriptionName(_config.SubscriptionName)
    .Topic(MyTopicName)
    .SubscriptionInitialPosition(SubscriptionInitialPosition.Earliest)
    .ReceiverQueueSize(_config.BatchSize.Value)
    .AckTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))
    .AckTimeoutTickTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))
    .EnableRetry(true)
    .NegativeAckRedeliveryDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    .DeadLetterPolicy(new DeadLetterPolicy(maxRedeliveryCount: 3))
    .SubscribeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Negative acks and retry/DLQ do work together. Negative acks are always enabled. The `NegativeAckRedeliveryDelay` is the delay the client waits before sending the NACK message to the broker. It is used to not retry immediately in case the failed handling of the message is due to a transient error.
With your config, if you continuously nack/timeout, the messages will be redelivered 3 times as per your `DeadLetterPolicy` then go to the default DLQ topic which is named `<topicname>-<subscriptionname>-DLQ` and not be redelivered anymore to the original topic.

Comment: Wait a second - you said it's the client that waits for the `NegativeAckRedeliveryDelay`? I thought it was the broker that managed that delay, only resending the message to the client after that delay...  That's why I was confused about how nack and retry work together.  When you nack and it gets redelivered, is it being redelivered _through_ the retry queue, or through some prior process?